Dynamically editing edges based on node attribute changes in Memgraph
I have two nodes and created an edge based on certain similarity. If I change the similar part in one node, I need to delete that relation immediately. How can I do this? I want to apply this for many nodes.
I found this in Memgraph documentation: [community_detection_online]1. Will it work for this specific case?

What you're mentioning is reminding me of our dynamic (streaming) graph algorithms.
Now, it depends what you exactly need to calculate, but once set right, these algorithms will update properties (eg. community property in community detection) whenever something changes in the graph that can affect that property.
